# insert/delete query design of website

Tags: php

I wonder what would be the professional way to handle insert/delete requests of a website?

Right now, what I have is I inserted two `<input type = "hidden"/>` on each form where one hidden's value correspond to a function it needs and the other is the parameter of this function. So when the form submits, I have a post.php file that handles ALL insert/delete requests that simply invokes the value of the hiddens via `call_user_func()` in PHP. Like so:

```
<input name = "arg" value = "{$id}" type = "hidden"/>
<input name = "call" value = "delete_member" type = "hidden"/>

call_user_func($_POST['call'], $_POST['arg']);
```

I'm having doubts on how sensible this solution is because I found out that the hiddens aren't actually hidden in the source on the client-side.

My first solution was to basically have a lot of conditionals checking for which function to invoke but I really hated that a lot so I changed it with this solution.

I wonder what are the better ways I can do this, or maybe how the professionals do it? Handling insert/delete queries.

Comment: *I found out that the hiddens aren't actually hidden in the source on the client-side* Huh, imagine that.

Comment: You have heard of MVC, right?

Comment: Rule 1: Never trust user input! Always sanitise and validate input. This also applies to your approach. Use `method_exists()` or `function_exists()` to check if the function or method exist. Pro tip: Create an own class which contains all allowed functions a user can call. With your approach now, what happens if the user sets "call" to `unlink` and "arg" to `/var/www/index.php`.

Comment: Look into a PHP framework, such as Zend Framework or similar. There are many, many frameworks with this very specific logic at their core.

Comment: That method of calling functions is so insanely insecure, someone could so easily abuse that to run anything they like.

Comment: I've separated the view part from the part that handles the processing via different files. Basically my index.php just renders a single object. However, my insert/delete requests are all just thrown to a single file. I think I understand MVC in principle, however this is the first web-based project I've done...

Comment: Look into how yii/lithium/zend/cakephp/kohana/etc do this, it is quite a mouth full to explain here.

Comment: @Shi yes, I do some checks on whether the function does exist. I guess I didn't put it there for simplicity of just illustrating my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this a very bad way to call actions from the client side.

For one this data is put into the HTML which will always be viewable and editable by the client. As such this means you cannot trust the data you receive from the client and as such you cannot trust the function they are calling.

Another point to re-inforce my previous idea. You say you run validation to make sure it is a function and all that, but you have a problem. Closures return true on these functions (since they are functions and methods and they exist). So a user can put a anon function as the value of your hiden field and actually run whatever they want on your server.

As others say I would recommend looking into MVC. Look into how Yii/CodeIgniter/Zend/Lithium/Kohana/etc do this and how they route.

An example of how routing for actions such as deletion is done by my favourite framework, Yii:

```
class UserController extends CController{
    public function actionDelete($id = null){
       if($id===null){ return false; }
    }
}
```

Then the form/link calls `/user/delete?id=2` which makes index.php route to the `userController` and use the `actionDelete` function inside the user controller, running it's code. Of course this is a very simplified version and it gets a lot more complex to stop vulnerabilities.

You may also wish to look into CSRF validation.

Comment: So it would be okay to have the operations in the URL/$_GET? My previous solutions goes something like `post.php?do=delete&what=member&id=2`...

Comment: @lightburst Well I guess it depends actually. How do you validate this function? If you are just saying, `is this a function in this file` then you are open to security problems. If you say `is this a function within this controller class?` then you might be fine providing you implement obvious security fixes

Comment: Well... I don't quite get what you mean. For both solutions, I check for whether the uniquely named submit button exists in the `$_POST`. You also would not be able to make it to the inner conditions, or be able to invoke any function, using the `$_GET` solution, without being logged or having my submit button names existing in `$_POST`. A variant of my `$_GET` solution is also to construct a string that will be called as a function(the `$_GET['do']` and `$_GET['what'] adds up to a name of a function...).

Comment: So the problem isn't that the user can run arbitrary code, but that they can invoke some other existing function they wanted? And that 'localizing' functions would do the trick? (basically narrowing down fellow functions within their space)

Comment: @lightburst Yes localising function by containing them to a class or something can help yes.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is to just call a function that takes care of one form at the time like this example for submitting a blog message:

**blog.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  save_message();
} else {
  display_form();
}

function display_form()
{
  ?>
  <form action="blog.php"> etc etc....
  <?php
}

function save_message()
{
  //security checks and inserts etc
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Form saved succesfully';
  header('location: blog_overview.php');
}
```

This is according to me a practish, but you might want to checkout frameworks like Codeigniter and Kohana since the above code is functional (and to me outdated). Read some tutorials about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) and MVC (Model View Controller). It might seem alot of work, but if you really want it to do it right it is worth the time and effort.

Comment: Note that this is a good way for starters to learn the syntax and how php handles functions etc. Take it to the next level (OOP and MVC) ASAP since unlearning bad habbits is harder then learning new stuff.

Comment: I have a lot of forms that does the same two things but with different classes of data. When I explicitly listed each condition, I ended up with a lot of nesting and/or awkward conditions...

Comment: I like to use a big `switch` statement with all my operation codes. Not very "elegant", but nice and simple.